# smart thermostat circuit needed some layout tips

Tags: schematics, eaglecad, layout

I have smart thermostat project for my graduation and I just wanted to be 100% sure before sending it to China for manufacturing - its my first time with PCBs O_O. It takes 3 weeks to arrive my country therefore I don’t have time to test it, I only got one shot. My prototype works perfectly on breadboard.

This is the dropbox link to my BRD files and some screenshot for you guys to check it real quick: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/05sbwndrdl5tqql/AADXK4_4RyO7QGvu2Xw_t1Hka?dl=0

I have few questions below, and I really do appreciate if you download them and control it.

1. Transmission traces between FT232 and Atmega328 are not short
   traces. Are these traces going to cause any trouble?
2. Did I place the decoupling capacitors correctly in my layout?
3. Is 16mil drill size too small for manufacturing?
4. Do I need to add a diode between LM3940 and ESP8266-1?

Transmitter:
[image]
[image]

Receiver:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Many of your traces are much longer than necessary, and some of your routing makes no sense. For instance, your USB data lines do it the hard way - you don't have to connect to the "outside" of the IC pads, so there is no need for your crossover. Plus, USB lines must be as short as possible - 480 MHz is nothing to take lightly. Also, you make a number of trace junctions at an acute angle. Don't. The acute angle is a built-in etchant trap. Make all joins at right angles.

Comment: i will consider it for sure. Do you see any other critical error ?

Answer (score 1):

If RS232 Test is not grounded, it will fail.
Read datasheet on all unused inputs for proper handling.

Shop around for 3 day turns on PCB. **You will need more debug time** than you expect 1st time.

Read and follow these rules as much as possible.
http://media.protoexpress.com/notouch-pcb-design-guidelines.pdf

I also high recommend this shop and others with similar capability.
But if you are on a tight budget.... How much does late cost?

Comment: wow i just have checked the datasheet and it is written "Must be tied to GND for normal operation". i imported most part of schematic from arduino nano which published in official arduino website as a open source ! Obviously it is not correct